# How to set VirtualBox disk size to fixed in Vagrantfile?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I've got a Vagrant box which uses the [vagrant-disksize](https://github.com/sprotheroe/vagrant-disksize) plugin to increase the size of a downloaded image. Since [some people argue that setting the disk size fixed is going to speed up adding files](https://www.howtogeek.com/124796/THE-HTG-GUIDE-TO-SPEEDING-UP-YOUR-VIRTUAL-MACHINES/) (and I have to add a lot of them) I would like to change this disk to be fixed size. How can I do that in the Vagrantfile after or at the same time as setting the disk size?